# Stanford CoreNLP Error creating edu.stanford.nlp.time.TimeExpressionExtractorImpl

Tags: c#, nlp, stanford-nlp

I am trying to learn the Stanford CoreNLP library. I am using C# with the posted example (https://sergeytihon.wordpress.com/2013/10/26/stanford-corenlp-is-available-on-nuget-for-fc-devs/).  I loaded the package “Stanford.NLP.CoreNLP” (it added IKVM.NET) via nuget and downloaded the code. Unzipped the .jar models. My directory is correct.  I get the following error:

```
> edu.stanford.nlp.util.ReflectionLoading.ReflectionLoadingException was
> unhandled HResult=-2146233088 Message=Error creating
> edu.stanford.nlp.time.TimeExpressionExtractorImpl
> Source=stanford-corenlp-3.5.0 StackTrace: at
> edu.stanford.nlp.util.ReflectionLoading.loadByReflection(String
> className, Object[] arguments) at
> edu.stanford.nlp.time.TimeExpressionExtractorFactory.create(String
> className, String name, Properties props) at
> edu.stanford.nlp.time.TimeExpressionExtractorFactory.createExtractor(String
> name, Properties props) at
> edu.stanford.nlp.ie.regexp.NumberSequenceClassifier..ctor(Properties
> props, Boolean useSUTime, Properties sutimeProps) at
> edu.stanford.nlp.ie.NERClassifierCombiner..ctor(Boolean
> applyNumericClassifiers, Boolean useSUTime, Properties nscProps,
> String[] loadPaths) at
> edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorImplementations.ner(Properties
> properties) at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorFactories.6.create()
> at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorPool.get(String name) at
> edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.construct(Properties A_1,
> Boolean A_2, AnnotatorImplementations A_3) at
> edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP..ctor(Properties props,
> Boolean enforceRequirements) at
> edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP..ctor(Properties props) at
> ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(String[] args) in
> d:\Programming_Code\VisualStudio\visual studio
> 2013\Projects\AutoWikify\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs:line
> 30 at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly,
> String[] args) at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly() at
> System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
> executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
> preserveSyncCtx) at
> System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
> executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
> preserveSyncCtx) at
> System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
> executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state) at
> System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart() InnerException:
> edu.stanford.nlp.util.MetaClass.ClassCreationException
> HResult=-2146233088 Message=MetaClass couldn’t create public
> edu.stanford.nlp.time.TimeExpressionExtractorImpl(java.lang.String,java.util.Properties)
> with args [sutime, {sutime.binders=0, annotators=tokenize, ssplit,
> pos, lemma, ner, parse, dcoref}] Source=stanford-corenlp-3.5.0
> StackTrace: at
> edu.stanford.nlp.util.MetaClass.ClassFactory.createInstance(Object[]
> params) at edu.stanford.nlp.util.MetaClass.createInstance(Object[]
> objects) at
> edu.stanford.nlp.util.ReflectionLoading.loadByReflection(String
> className, Object[] arguments) InnerException:
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException HResult=-2146233088
> Message=”” Source=stanford-corenlp-3.5.0 StackTrace: at __(Object[] )
> at
> Java_sun_reflect_ReflectionFactory.FastConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Object[]
> args) at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Object[] initargs,
> CallerID ) at
> edu.stanford.nlp.util.MetaClass.ClassFactory.createInstance(Object[]
> params) InnerException:
```

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using java.util;
using java.io;
using edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline;
using Console = System.Console;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{
// Path to the folder with models extracted from `stanford-corenlp-3.4-models.jar`
var jarRoot = @”D:\Programming_SDKs\stanford-corenlp-full-2015-01-30\stanford-corenlp-3.5.1-models\”;

// Text for processing
var text = “Kosgi Santosh sent an email to Stanford University. He didn't get a reply.”;

// Annotation pipeline configuration
var props = new Properties();
props.setProperty(“annotators”, “tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, dcoref”);
props.setProperty(“sutime.binders”, “0”);

// We should change current directory, so StanfordCoreNLP could find all the model files automatically
var curDir = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
System.IO.Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(jarRoot);
var pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
System.IO.Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(curDir);

// Annotation
var annotation = new Annotation(text);
pipeline.annotate(annotation);

// Result – Pretty Print
using (var stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream())
{
pipeline.prettyPrint(annotation, new PrintWriter(stream));
Console.WriteLine(stream.toString());
stream.close();
}
}
}
}
```

Comment: Is there some way to get only results obtained by one of the processes mentioned in pipeline?
In java we used to do it by giving the class name for which we need the result as following: `String pos = token.get(CoreAnnotations.PartOfSpeechAnnotation.class);` Here, I have obtained only the part of speech tag results for the pipeline `Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse");
        StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);`

Comment: They fixed it with latest nuget release.

Comment: Can you please give a sample or link to documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3.5.1 is currently (2/11/2015) not supported.  It works with

http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-corenlp-full-2014-10-31.zip

Comment: They fixed original problem with latest nuget release.

Comment: 3.5.2 is still causing this exception to be thrown.

Comment: Seems 3.6.0 also causes this, if someone has any other information please advice.

Answer (score 15):

Adding `props.setProperty("ner.useSUTime", "false")` fixed this for me.

Comment: OMG that worked, after hours and hours of scouring the internet!  thanks.  Just a note, because I am a total newbie and perhaps there are others... I added this code to the line after         Properties props = new Properties();

Comment: I added the above 'setProperty' call to the line just above the call to new StanfordCoreNLP (props); which is where it had been failing. This is still a problem up to the current version: CoreNLP version 3.9.0, Java version 9.0.1.

Comment: Plus Eclipse needed a Heap Size of 4GB in order to run the demo program without crashing. See elsewhere on how to increase the Heap Size.