# TypeInitializationException when running Stanford.NLP.CoreNLP example

Tags: .net, f#, stanford-nlp

I'm trying to run the **F#** sample from http://sergey-tihon.github.io/Stanford.NLP.NET/StanfordCoreNLP.html.

The project is .NET porting of Java Stanford NLP libraries, so I'm wondering if this could be an **IKVM** issue rather.

I'm running the sample code inside an **F#** console application for **NET 4.5** and **F# Core 3.1**. I've also downloaded `models` from the correct jar and changed the path in the code.

This is the raised exception:

```
System.TypeInitializationException was unhandled
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in StanfordNLPNETFs.exe
Additional information: The type initializer for '.$Program' threw an exception.
```

In the second post of the issue I reported on GitHub, there's also a screenshot: https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/1194228/9424606/4aef5e0e-48f2-11e5-9690-c2668303d225.png.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you're hitting the [known issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28389564/stanford-corenlp-error-creating-edu-stanford-nlp-time-timeexpressionextractorimp) of Stanford-NLP distribution that comes and goes with nuget versions/java distributions.

In any case, adding the following property setting to annotation pipeline configuration should allow the given sample code to run successfully with latest `Stanford.NLP.CoreNLP ver 3.5.2` nuget:

```
props.setProperty("ner.useSUTime", "false") |> ignore
```

Comment: now I can exactly the output of the sample. +1 and this answers my question! Now I'll try to explore the library that gives a more **F#** idiomatic access to Stanford-NLP libs.

Answer (score 0):

Change the culture in .NET to "US".

```
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("en-US");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;

tagger = new MaxentTagger(modelsDirectory + @"\french.tagger");
```

I had the same problem. On 2 computers it works fine and on 2 other it does not. So I figured it was something in the environment related to time, so I changed the culture. I am working with the POS tagger for French text.